# How chemically homogeneous is air?

Tags: atmospheric-chemistry

By this, I mean if I buy compressed dry air from somebody like British Oxygen how much variation in composition might I expect between batches? For example, is Argon evenly distributed globally, by height, by geography etc? Is $\ce{CO2}$ removed? Are contaminants filtered out eg $\ce{NOx}$?

Answer (score 8):

Oxygen/nitrogen ratios [vary seasonally](http://bluemoon.ucsd.edu/publications/ralph/3_Seasonal.pdf) and geographically even at sea level on the order of 200 ppm.  Oxygen concentration has also been slowly decreasing in correlation with carbon dioxide increase.

Try using the [MSIS-E-90 Atmosphere Model](http://ccmc.gsfc.nasa.gov/modelweb/models/msis_vitmo.php) which allow location, date, time and height input and provides composition output.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking of the possibility of replacing Argon with air in a calibration experiment, but it now looks like "air" is not as pure as I would like.